# Name for non-Salafiyya non-Reform Islam

Tags: sunni, salafi

I am looking for a name for the Islam that is not part of any direction of reform movement (Salafist, Salafi, Fundamental Reform, Modern Reform, Liberal Islam), i.e. following the four schools of Sunni Islam (possibly including similar traditional Shia schools). I would say «conservative» Islam but I do not have the impression that this is a commonly understood term. Is there a more-or-less established term in English or Arabic?

Comment: What are you looking for?

Comment: looking for a name for the normal,  main stream, usual., traditional majority Islam as it has grown through the centuries, with schools of fiqh having their principles and traditions so that I could say all those say this see here and there but salafi say...